# Are template variables thread safe? they're placed on data segment?

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, c++14, data-segment, variable-templates

I'm playing with the new template variables feature from C++14 in order to get used to it (maybe is soon to do this 'cause it seems that some compilers didn't implement it completely).

Now I'm wondering where lies each instance of a template variable. In the tests I did so far they seem to be initialized before any static data so I'm wondering if they're placed in the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) of the program. Let's see what I've tryed so far, I have a class which prints information on construction and destruction:

```
struct squealer
{
    squealer(std::string a_name) : m_name(a_name) { std::cout << this << ' ' << m_name << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    ~squealer() { std::cout << this << ' ' << m_name << ' ' << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
    void f() {}
    const std::string m_name;
};
```

And a program which instances some `squealer`s in local storage, static storage and as template variables, this is the program:

```
// static storage squealer
squealer s("\"static\"");

// template variable squealer
template <int i> squealer test(std::string(i, 'A'));

// function using a template variable squealer
void f() { test<1>.f(); }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // local storage squealer
    squealer ss("local");

    // using another template variable squealers
    test<2>.f();
    switch (argc)
    {
        case 1: test<3>.f(); break;
        case 2: test<4>.f(); break;
        case 3: test<5>.f(); break;
        case 4: test<6>.f(); break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the program](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ExfTbYO2PjNAyGG4) and this is the output:

```
A squealer::squealer(std::string)
AA squealer::squealer(std::string)
AAA squealer::squealer(std::string)
AAAA squealer::squealer(std::string)
AAAAA squealer::squealer(std::string)
AAAAAA squealer::squealer(std::string)
"static" squealer::squealer(std::string)
local squealer::squealer(std::string)
local squealer::~squealer()
"static" squealer::~squealer()
AAAAAA squealer::~squealer()
AAAAA squealer::~squealer()
AAAA squealer::~squealer()
AAA squealer::~squealer()
AA squealer::~squealer()
A squealer::~squealer()
```

As we can see, all the template variables `squealer` instances are created before the one named `"static"` and at the end (as expected) the one named `local` is created, the destruction order is the opposite (as expected too), so: the order of creation/initialization of template variables instances is the same of its appearance on the code regardless of the locality of this appearance and regardless of they're used or not (the `f()` function is never called).

So the first question is, are this template variables placed on the data segment? I don't know how to test or check it.

The second question is, are all of this template variables `squealer` instances thread safe? I've readed on [n3376 §6.7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf) the following sentence (emphasis mine):

> An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of other block-scope variables with static or thread storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). **Otherwise such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization**. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. **If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization**.

From C++11 if all of the template variable `squealer` instances are in static storage they should be thread safe, isn't it?

Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of thread safety, it's not a good idea to use `std::cout` in the constructor of `squealer` because it may not be created yet.

Comment: @AntonSavin any better alternative to `std::cout` to trace the status of an object being created?

Comment: I believe, only `printf()`. May someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of the standard you quote describes **block-scope** variables with static storage duration, e.g:

```
int foo() {
  static int bar = 42;
  return bar;
}
```

of which your program has none. All of your variables with static storage duration are declared at namespace scope, so you need to be looking at [basic.start.init] (3.6.2). Specifically paragraph two which states:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.
>
> ...
>
> Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is *unordered* if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is *ordered* [ *Note:* an explicitly specialized
>   static data member or variable template specialization has ordered initialization. —*end note* ] Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their
>   definitions in the translation unit. If a program starts a thread (30.3), the subsequent initialization of a variable is unsequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit. Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit. If a program starts a thread, the subsequent unordered initialization of a variable is unsequenced with respect to every other dynamic initialization. Otherwise,
>   the unordered initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to every other dynamic initialization.

In the question's program, all the `squealer` instances with static storage duration must be dynamically initialized since `squealer` has a member `std::string` that cannot be constant-initialized. `::s` has ordered initialization, and all of the instances of `test` have unordered initialization since each is an "implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization" of the template `test`. The `test` instances are guaranteed to be initialized before entering `main`, but otherwise all bets are off: they may be initialized in any order, possibly before and/or after initialization of `::s` and more importantly `std::cout`. Those initializations are notably *not* thread-safe: "If a program starts a thread, the subsequent unordered initialization of a variable is unsequenced with respect to every other dynamic initialization."

Comment: What a pity, I really thought that they were thread safe (I'm glad I asked though)... but you pointed that the initialization is unordered, why unordered initialization implies thread unsafe? and what about thread safety **after** initialization (i.e: accessing) what about the question of *data segment*? Did you know anything about this topic? Thanks for your efforts and patience.

Comment: They're variables so they're treated like variables. In general there's no thread-safety unless you explicitly ask for it. Static local variables are an exception. You can probably forget about this "data segment" thing which doesn't have much to do with C++.

Answer (score 1):

Variable template specializations are static variables as stated by [temp.inst]/12:

> Implicitly instantiated class, function, and variable template specializations are placed in the namespace where the template is defined.

Therefore, usual static initialization rules apply, which means that all specializations are initialized before `main()` executes.

Comment: Yes, I've already seen that they're initialized before `main()` executes. But in my example code I'm not using variable template specializations. Can you link the document of your quote in order to get a look to it?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster all `test<N>`s in your code are implicitly instantiated specializations of `test`.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought that a specialization is this: `template<> int test<100>{};` <-- specialization of `test` for the value `100`. And the ones from my example are *instances* not *specializations*... that's what i thought.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster what you wrote is *explicit* specialization.